# GitLab shows collaborator with GitHub account

Tags: git

I have a GitLab repo and it has 167 commits. I also have GitHub repo with different name but with the same project.

I have added a colaborator named "X" in GitHub (NOT in GitLab) and he has done some changes in GitHub and pushes to GitHub. But when I see on the GitLab side it shows the collaborator X even though X does not have a GitLab account. Why?
Can X can leave that GitLab by himself?

Answer (score 0):

Every commit has associated with it the name and email ID of the user who made the commit, which is independent of any account on GitLab or GitHub. If there is an account, the commit email ID is used to attribute the commit to the appropriate account.

But even if there isn't, X's name will be visible if they used it when committing, only it won't link to their profile (since none exists). You can check the commit authors of past commits locally using `git log`.